# How to include *.min.* in Release and *.* in Debug Builds and preserve parent folder?

Tags: msbuild, winjs

I want to include the WinJS source in my project. It comes with minified versions of its `*.js` and `*.css` files. To save space I want to include only the minified versions with `Release configurations`.

That's what I have come up with so far:

```
<Content Include="WinJS\css\*.css;WinJS\js\*.js" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'">
  <Link>WinJS\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
<Content Include="WinJS\css\*.min.css;WinJS\js\*.min.js" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'">
  <Link>WinJS\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

There are 2 problems with that:

1. The `Debug Configuration` also contains the `.min.*` files. That would be a minor problem.
2. (more importantly) The parent folder of the files is lost when using `RecursiveDir` that way
3. In `Release Configuration` the `.min` part should be dropped, so that I can reference the files always with one name in my code (`<script src="/WinJS/js/WinJS.js"/>`)

The expected result in the project should always be:

```
WinJS/css/ui-light.css
WinJS/css/ui-dark.css
WinJS/js/WinJS.js
```

either coming from the `.min` versions in `Release Configuration` or the non-minified versions in `Debug Configuration`.

Maybe something clever could be done combining `Include` and `Exclude`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%(RecursiveDir) items metadata are available just in case you use wildchar **.
See documenation of [MSBuild Well-known Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I’m don't use WinJS but in case Link metadata are used in places where you need reference the files js and css files this could be solution for you:

```
<Content Include="WinJS\**\*.css;WinJS\**\*.js" Exclude="WinJS\**\*.min.css;WinJS\**\*.min.js" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" >
  <Link>WinJS\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
<Content Include="WinJS\**\*.min.css;WinJS\**\*.min.js" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'">
  <Link>WinJS\%(RecursiveDir)$([System.String]::Copy("(Filename)").Replace(".min",""))%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

Comment: When replacing the `&quot;` with real double quotes it works. Thanks!